Can I profile my pip requirements installation to see which ones take time?
I'm looking for a way to sort the requirements of a project, depending to the time they typically need to be downloaded and installed.
I'm aware this time may have a huge variance depending on a lot of external parameters, but I guess it should still be possible to tell which packages cost the most time.
It would help a lot to decrease my build time (on containers), since I could find workarounds to avoid using some packages, if only I'd know which ones are the more time-consuming at build.
The size of the packages can be found easily, but the time of installation itself is not displayed by package. Is there simply a proportional relationship between both?

EDIT
Due to the technical stack we are using here (GCP Cloud functions, a high-level managed system), I do not have much power on the ways containers are build, that's why I'm looking for optimising requirements.

There is certainly not a simple proportional relationship between package size and its installation time. A package install can be as simple as writing a file to the filesystem, or as complicated as installing a toolchain and compiling extensions to binary. Thus, a relatively small package may take much longer to install than downloading a single zipfile and writing it to the filesystem. This is a complex topic. One resource to look at is https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/

Do you need that much time that you are looking into workaround ? Maybe put a list of your requirements as well

If you use the --log <filename> option for pip, you'll get a log file with timestamps; that may help.

Also look into a smaller docker image maybe ? It will be massive speed up

If you cache your layers then rebuilding a container wouldn't need to install the packages again (provided you install them somewhere near the top of your dockerfile). You would need to eat the build time once, but that's minimal compared to everything else that Docker needs to build a container

I'll go out on a limb and say I think this is actually a pretty worthwhile question, without anything about Docker and caching. Anything that takes long enough to build that it matters is probably either not PEP517 compliant or is a complex enough extension that it can't be pre-built easily for lots of architectures. Knowing the build times to tune would be really useful.

pip isn't designed to be user-serviced, but it is, after all, a python program. Have you tried profiling it as such, using cProfile?

you can always write script which runs pip on every module separately - and you can use time to measure time for every execution.
